# Unable to deploy war file using Tomcat Manager

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat

I am unable to deploy war file using Tomcat Manager
My \Tomcat\conf\tomcat-users.xml looks like below:

```
<!--
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>    
<user name="tomcat" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>
-->
```

Also, edited \Servers\Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config\tomcat-users.xml to

```
<!--
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>    
<user name="tomcat" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>
-->
```

Still it is showing below error on launching server as   http://localhost:8080/manager/html and providing appropriate credentials

```
401 Unauthorized

You are not authorized to view this page. If you have not changed any configuration files, please examine the file conf/tomcat-users.xml in your installation. That file must contain the credentials to let you use this webapp.

For example, to add the manager-gui role to a user named tomcat with a password of s3cret, add the following to the config file listed above.
```

I have also tried adding manager.xml to \Tomcat\conf but nothing worked

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.0\.0\.1" />
</Context>
```

Note: I am restarting the server and http://localhost:8080/ is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<role>` and `<user>` tags are just plain text in an XML comment, surrounded by `<!--` and `-->`. Remove the beginning and end of comment.

```
<!--    <<< BEGINNING OF COMMENT. Remove this line
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>    
<user name="tomcat" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,standard,manager-gui"/>
-->     <<< END OF COMMENT.       Remove this line
```

Answer (score 1):

You need un-comment user entry in `tomcat-users.xml`.

You need add users to `/tomcat-users.xml` otherwise you can't deploy war file through manager app.

Example:

```
<user username="craigmcc" password="secret" roles="standard,manager-script" />
```

More [configuration details are here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access).